# IntegrityError UNIQUE on blog_post.slog despite creating unique slug function

Tags: django

I am new to django and somewhat new to python too.

I am trying to create a simple blog application and as we all know you want to have unique slugs for your blog links. However I cannot seem to rid myself of this UNIQUE error.

### Problem description

When I create a blog post I create a slug from the title. Then I see if that slug matches any others in the database. If it does, I add a little string to the end.

Nevertheless, the database keeps throwing an IntegrityError.

### What I've tried

I have been using `import pdb; pdb.stack_trace()` to try to trace the issue. It seems to me to happen after setting `self.object.slug` and then doing `self.object.save()`. Somehow the unique slug is may not be be being passed to `save.()`. But I'm not sure how to debug beyond this point. I'd appreciate help in the debugging process.

The confusing thing is that I'm working from a (functioning) django blog app. I cannot find the difference between my code and that one, and I've tried changing the `methods.py` and `views.py` to match that of the other blog, and yet that app produces unique slugs and throws no errors, while mine does not.

I've tried rebuilding the database as well and starting from scratch.

### Places I haven't looked

`get_absolute_url()`: I don't know why this would be an issue, but I haven't tried debugging it. I don't exactly know how `reverse()` works and reading about that is my project for the morning.

`template.html`: I'm not sure why the template would be the issue.

### Relevant code

Please let me know if I should post something else.

```
from .models import post
from .helpers in get_post_slug

class PostCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_create.html'
    fields = ['title', 'published_at', 'body']
    success_message = "'%(title)s' was created"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.slug = get_post_slug(self.object.title)

        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
from .models import Post
import uuid

def get_post_slug(post_title):
    slug = slugify(post_title)
    if Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
        slug += "-" + str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
    return slug
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published_at = models.DateField(
        default=timezone.now,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="Leave blank to keep as draft/unpublished. Use a future date for auto-posting.",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={"slug":self.slug})

    class Meta:
            ordering = ["-published_at", "-created_at",]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, amazingly, but I don't know why this worked.

```
class Meta:
            ordering = ["-published_at", "-created_at",]
```

has an extra comma. That extra comma was interfering with the slug creation causing an IntegrityError. Go figure.